# Is there a way to know if an R script is running directly or within another script?

Tags: r

I am using R studio.

Is there a way to know if an R script is running directly either by the source command in the console) or within another script. ie. another script is sourced and this has the call to the first script.

This can be useful to prompt for some values in some cases.

What I am doing now is to set a variable to true or false and within the script I check for that variable. This works but an automatic way is better.

Thanks for your time.

## EDIT:  More info

Let's say I have an independent script that runs fine as is, but this script is part of a process to run after another script finished. If I have to run both, I can run the first, then the second; but also I have the chance just to run the second.

What I am asking is if there is a way to (in the second script) to verify if this second was called from the first or no.

Take a look at his simple examples (inspired by the answer from [Greg Snow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865382/5861244)). First the file I call in Rstudio

```
# scripta.R
writeLines("script A")
if (interactive()) writeLines("interactive: true") else writeLines("interactive false")
source("scriptb.r")
writelines("after B")
```

Then the file being sourced

```
# scriptb.R
writeLines("script B")
if (interactive()) writeLines("interactive: true") else writeLines("interactive false")
writeLines("end B")
```

The result in Rstudio is

```
script A
interactive: true
script B
interactive: true
end B
after B
```

I like to have something like

```
script A
interactive: true
script B
interactive: false
end B
after B
```

I hope now is more clear.

Thanks

Comment: Could you shed a bit more light on why you use this setup? It sounds a bit arcane to me...

Answer (score 7):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a related one is to look at the `interactive` function.  This function will return `TRUE` if R believes that you are in an interactive session and it is reasonable to assume a person is available to answer questions, it will return `FALSE` if running in BATCH mode and it is fairly certain that there are no humans (or aliens, intelligent animals, etc.) to answer questions.

Not exactly what you were asking, but it may be helpful for deciding whether to prompt for information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently R studio set this as TRUE and I cannot get anything else. This is kind what I am looking for. I just added more information to my question just in case.

Comment: @notuo, If you have complete control over both scripts, then the best approach is probably to create a variable or set an option in script A, then in script B check the option or existence of the variable, then in script A change the option or variable before exit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, a simple `message()` command should do what (I think) you need. Since you are calling one of several scripts based on logical checks, then having a message echoed at the start of each script like:

`message("R has now entered script_1.R \n")`

should do it. If a script is never called because some variable is set to `FALSE`, then you will never see this message.

If you need to prompt for, and read values from the console, then inserting a line like:

`new_input <- readline("Enter a value for x: ")`

would also be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

This may do it. First the script you run

```
# script-A.R
cat("script A\n")
if (interactive()) 
  cat("interactive: true\n") else cat("interactive: false\n")

source_func <- function(file){
  # check that the variable does not exist already
  pa <- .GlobalEnv
  has_old <- if(exists("is_sourced", where = pa))
    stop(sQuote("is_sourced"), " exists already")
  pa$is_sourced <- TRUE
  # make sure to remove the variable again
  on.exit(rm(is_sourced, envir = pa)) 
  source(
    file, 
    # .GlobalEnv is used anyway but now it is easy to change to another environment
    local = pa) 

  invisible()
}

source_func("script-B.R")
cat("after B\n")
```

Then the script you source

```
# script-B.R
if(!exists("is_sourced"))
  if(!interactive())
    # throw an error if interactive and `is_sourced` is not set
    is_sourced <- FALSE else stop("Set ", sQuote("is_sourced"))

if (interactive() && !is_sourced) 
  cat("interactive: true\n") else cat("interactive: false\n")
cat("end B\n")
```

Result of running `script-A.R` is

```
script A
interactive: true
script B
interactive: false
end B
after B
```

Comment: I saw Greg Snow's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864647/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-an-r-script-is-running-directly-or-within-another-scri/54158372#comment82074332_10865382) now. This is answer is quite close to what he describes.